# Alamofire: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, alamofire

Good Day.

I have a iOS Swift Application that communicates with a companies already created API and its communicated with using Alamofire. The problem I have is the API can possibly return nulls some time and this causes the following problem:

"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

My code snippet that reads from the dictionary is as follows:

```
if let LowRate = HotelList[i]["LowRate"] as? Decimal!{ 
    HList._LowRate = LowRate
}
```

I have reviewed multiple questions and google sites however I need a way to check the object in the dictionary for null before its processed or I need to set some type of default value.

The Json null example is as follows

```
 HotelData = "<null>";
        HotelList =(
           {
                Address1 = "124 Oceanview Road";
                Address2 = Oneroa;
                BookingUrl = "<null>";
                City = " Auckland";
                Country = "New Zealand";
                CurrencyCode = "<null>";
                DateViewed = "<null>";
                Description = "<null>";
                Directions = "<null>";
                Distance = "<null>";
                GeoPoint = "<null>";
                HighRate = "<null>";
                ImageUrl = "<null>";
                LowRate = "<null>";
                MinChildAge = "<null>";
                Name = "The Oyster Inn";
                NavUrl = "<null>";
                PostalCode = "<null>";
                State = "<null>";
                WebsiteUrl = "<null>";
                distance = "<null>";
                hotelID = 130;
                isActive = 1;
                isBlocked = 0;
                isChildrenAllowed = "<null>";
                isFavorite = 0;
                isPromoNotified = 0;
                showDouble = "<null>";
}
         );
        RowCount = 11;
        hasError = 0;
    };
```

I am using Alamofire for my json and it works unless there is a null returned in one of the 20 fields that could possibly return a null.

Can anyone assist me in doing some validation checks for the result of a null as shown above while unwrapping an optional.

Regards

Comment: `as? Decimal!` Don't force unwrap. Replace the `!` with another level of `if let` and handle the possibility of nil.

Comment: Good Day. Thank you for your reply could you give me an example of replacing a "!" with an "if let" for nil validation? Regards

Comment: You have an example in your own code. :) This is also explained everywhere already, search for "optionals" and "optional binding" (which is the name of the `if let` system).

Comment: You are trying to LowRate string as decimal, check with casting,  Intead of decimal change as? string and type caste it appropriate type

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply it will most of the time be a decimal and can possibly be a null. I need to validate that if it isnt a decimal if itrs null i need to default it

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do this.(Updated)

```
if let lowRate = json["LowRate"], !(lowRate is NSNull){
   print(lowRate)
}else{
   print("null")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! `!(variable is NSNull)` worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

Good Day

Thanks to all the contributions to helping me find my answer. What worked in the end was something very similar to above I had to use a NSNumber object and then cast it to a decimal later along the lines please see code below.

```
if let lowRate = HotelList[i]["LowRate"] as? NSNumber{  

 HList._LowRate = LowRate

}else{

   print("Null")

}
```

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Your json has array of only one object. What is the value of i? If it's greater than 0 it will crash.

Comment: try HotelList[i]["LowRate"] as? Decimal?

Comment: Hi I will try this now and get back to you